# UndefVarError: showgraphics not defined，what？

Tags: julia

```
global myVar = spzeros(10,1);
myVar[3] = 1;

function test_base()
  test1();
end

function test1()
  myVar = [ i > 0 ? 2 : 0 for i in myVar] #doesn't work
end
```

I explicitly declare a variable global and then try to modify it inside a function. However when I attempt to run the function test1(), it says that the variable is undefined.

```
julia> VERSION
v"0.3.5"

julia> include("test.jl")
test1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> test_base()
ERROR: myVar not defined
 in test1 at /home/clifton/Julia/ca-1/test.jl:9
 in test_base at /home/clifton/Julia/ca-1/test.jl:5
```

I've tried different things, and it does work if I just access the variable in test1(), like print(myVar); Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Holy Moly!  That's an old version!  We're on 0.6.2 now.  I think you'll want to use a recent version of Julia.

Comment: add `global` before `myVar` in the function `test1`?